# How to get ID of selected item of jquery autocomplete in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete

in my jquery autocomplete textbox I want to show the "title" value from database and my code works fine but I want that when a user clicks one result, redirect him to this page:

ArticleDetails.aspx?ID=@ID

but my code is passing the "title" field and 
I don't know how to pass the "ID" field from database to that href.

this is my code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestSearch" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $("#SearchText").autocomplete({
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    window.location.href = 'ArticleDetails.aspx?ID=' + ui.item.value;
                },
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "TestSearch.aspx/Getauto",
                        data: "{'title':'" + document.getElementById('SearchText').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("ERROR!!!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="SearchText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is code-behind:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class TestSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchText.Text = null;
    }

    public class RespObj
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<RespObj> Getauto(string title)
    {
        List<RespObj> result = new List<RespObj>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpMySearch", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", title);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(new RespObj(){
                        label = dr["title"].ToString(),
                        value = dr["id"].ToString()
                    });
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Ui should also Support if you use an array of Json objects with the properties Label and value. So in the response from your server you have to return a Json array of this objects.

Maybe you change the server Code to something like this:

```
class RespObj {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<RespObj> Getauto(string title)
{
    List<RespObj> result = new List<RespObj>();
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpMySearch", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", title);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(new RespObj(){
                    label = dr["title"].ToString(),
                    value = dr["id"].ToString()
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

On the client you maybe need to parse the Jsonarray. So just change the line in succes to this.

```
response(JSON.parse(data));
```

And now you should be able to access the value propertie and get the related id.

Comment: I edited my code but I'm getting syntax error!

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Source Error:


Line 35:             {
Line 36:                 result.Add(new RespObj(){
Line 37:                     label: dr["title"].ToString(),
Line 38:                     value: dr["id"].ToString()
Line 39:                 });

Comment: Did you set all Brackets etc. right? Can you post your Code?

Comment: Ok sorry wrong language :) You need to use a `label = value` instead of `label: value`... I'll update my answer ... Sorry

Comment: tnx man...you make my day...I edited and updated the code & now everything works fine...